# Forward the shell from the base image to child image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

My projects need to access private go modules and to access to modules it needs a GOPROXY.
So I've create an image from base image **golang alpine**

**PROXY IMAGE:**

```
FROM golang:1.16.4-alpine3.13 AS builder

ARG GITLAB_LOGIN
ARG GITLAB_TOKEN

modules.
WORKDIR /app

ENV GO111MODULE="auto"
ENV GONOSUMDB=*.someting.text
ENV GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
ENV GOPRIVATE="gitlab.something.text"
#ARG GOPROXY=http://localhost:41732,https://proxy.golang.org,direct
RUN apk add --no-cache git

RUN echo "machine gitlab.something.text login ${GITLAB_LOGIN} password ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc

COPY ["go.mod", "go.sum", "./"]
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build \
    -installsuffix 'static' \
    -o /app/proxy .

FROM scratch AS final

COPY --from=builder /app /app
CMD [ "/app/proxy"]
```

And the alpine image has a shell so I can execute commands with **RUN**.
But then I want to use my proxy image as a base image.

**IMAGE THAT USES THE PROXY IMAGE:**

```
FROM proxy:latest

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download && go mod verify

COPY . .
RUN go build -o bin/app .

CMD [ "/app" ]
```

And then the image that is using the proxy image cannot access the shell.
So my question is, is there a way to forward/pass the shell from the base alpine image through the proxy image so the images that use the proxy image can access the shell that is provided by the alpine image.

Cause the error I get in the image that is using the proxy image as the base is

```
CI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

but of course this error does not happen in the proxy image cause it's base image is alpine.

Comment: It sounds like your proxy image is built `FROM scratch`; you can change that to be `FROM ubuntu` or `FROM alpine` if you need more functionality in it.  Do you have a [mcve] including both Dockerfiles?

Comment: The proxy image is build with the golang alpine image, I've edit the question to include the files contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final stage of the proxy image is built `FROM scratch`.  As you note this contains absolutely nothing, not even a shell, so if you want to use it as a base image, you need to change this to something else:

```sh
FROM golang:1.16.4-alpine3.13 AS builder
...
FROM alpine:3.13 # AS final
COPY --from=builder /app/proxy /usr/local/bin/proxy
CMD ["proxy"]
```

However, your Go build sequence produces a static binary; if it can run successfully as the only thing in a `FROM scratch` image then it can run successfully in any Linux environment.  You can [`COPY --from`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) an image as well as a build stage.  It might be easier to not use the proxy as a base image, but instead copy it into other images where you need it:

```sh
FROM golang # not the proxy
# Get the proxy binary from the other image
COPY --from=proxy /app/proxy /usr/local/bin
# Build the Go application as above
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
...
```